# 'WeakMap' is undefined with Angular 4 and Internet Explorer

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, systemjs

I write my first Angular 4 application and it's work fine in Chrome and Mozilla Firefox.

In both 10 and 11 version of Internet Explorer doesn't works.

I get **(SystemJS) ReferenceError: 'WeakMap' is undefined** 
on traspiled main.js.

This is my references to external javascript library and SystemJs configuration:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/es6-shim"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/reflect-metadata"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/zone.js?main=browser"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.31/dist/system.js"></script>
<script>
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
        },
        map: {
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'npm:@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.3.0',
        },
        packages: {
            '': {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

This is main.ts file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

import  { AppModule } from './app.module';

enableProdMode();

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

This is my tsconfig.json configuration

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./Scripts"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I not explicity use WeakMap.
I use only this imports inside files of application:

```
import { NgModule, enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Thanks You

Comment: It seems that `WeakMap` is not that supported for IE 10 and 11. Out of curiosity, can you share your use case with `WeakMap`? There are possibilities that you can design your app differently.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this issue on IE10. It does work on IE11 for me. Anyway, I included this polyfill and at least the page works - haven't tested it exhaustively though....

[WeakMap Polyfill](https://github.com/Benvie/WeakMap)

https://github.com/Benvie/WeakMap

Steve